# Intersecting Boolean Not Working

Tags: modeling, geometry, 3d-printing, boolean-modifier

I used to use C4D, but have moved to blender since it is free. I am trying to recreate a 3D printing project I had done in C4D but am struggling. (I am using Mac btw. Idk if that’s important)

I am trying to make two intersecting words to build a puzzle of sorts once it is printed. In c4d, I believe I used an intersecting boolean (it’s been awhile). I was able to get it to kind of work in blender, but it doesn’t look smooth at all. The faces from converted text look gross and are all triangular. This messes up the intersected boolean.

Because the faces were wonky from the converted type object, I tried fixing the topography based on a youtube video I found. It helped great and I got the new word geom to look fantastic once extruded! But when I tried to used the boolean, it didn’t look right. It’s almost like it’s not treating the geometry as if it is solid. It deletes some faces and doesnt show the full thing. Im really stumped and at my wits end. I’ll attach some photos I hope will help describe my situation better. If you need any more info from me, please let me know! I really need to try to figure this out.

Thank you so much for any help! If you need more info or photos please let me know!

This is the end goal:
[image]

These are the geometry builds I am using:[image]
[image]
The video I used to make the fixed geometry topography is this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3WJwsPk_mw)

This is the failed boolean with the above geometry in use:
[image]

This is the boolean that technically worked but the converted text to geom topography made it all crunchy:
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file (don't apply the Boolean modifier): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Also could you define what you mean by "crunchy", are you talking about the shading?

Answer (score 0):

this is actually a fairly easy fix, you just need to ensure it is shaded smooth, then go to your normals in the object data property's tab are checked

[image]

i hope this helps.